# AutoMapper - Map from object to enum

Tags: c#, .net, object, enums, automapper

I have this class:

```cs
public class EntityClass
{
    public bool IsExempt { get; set; }
    public bool IsOverdue { get; set; }
    public SourceEnum Status { get; set; }
}
```

And these two enums:

```cs
public enum SourceEnum
{
    NotSet = 0,
    InProgress,
    Submitted,
    AssessmentComplete,
    Complete
}

[Flags]
public enum DestinationEnum
{
    None = 0,

    [Description("Exempt")]
    Exempt = 1,

    [Description("Unset")]
    Unset = 2,

    [Description("Overdue")]
    Overdue = 3,

    [Description("In Progress")]
    InProgress = 4,

    [Description("Submitted")]
    Submitted = 5,

    [Description("Conf. Pending")]
    ConfirmationPending = 6,

    [Description("Complete")]
    Completed = 7
}
```

I want to map from `EntityClass` to `DestinationEnum`, I tried it this way:

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<EntityClass, DestinationEnum>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.IsExempt ? DestinationEnum.Exempt : DestinationEnum.None))
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.IsOverdue ? DestinationEnum.Overdue : DestinationEnum.None))

                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Status == SourceEnum.InProgress ? DestinationEnum.InProgress : DestinationEnum.None))
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Status == SourceEnum.Complete ? DestinationEnum.Completed : DestinationEnum.None))
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Status == SourceEnum.AssessmentComplete ? DestinationEnum.ConfirmationPending : DestinationEnum.None))
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Status == SourceEnum.Submitted ? DestinationEnum.Submitted : DestinationEnum.None))
                .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Status == SourceEnum.NotSet ? DestinationEnum.Unset : DestinationEnum.None)));

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var entityClassObj = new EntityClass { IsExempt = true, IsOverdue = true, Status = SourceEnum.InProgress };

var result = mapper.Map<DestinationEnum>(entityClassObj);
```

When I run my code, it returns:

> Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level
> individual members on a type.

I tried the solution from [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers) but unfortunately the `IncludeMembers` method is not available. I am using AutoMapper 6.0.2.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: Sorry but I think this approach doesn't work in my case because I have two boolean values and I need to map them to different enum values.

Comment: That's _totally_ irrelevant. Anything you can do in C#, you can do with a type converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lucian mentioned, you need to implement the [Custom Type Converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html) for your scenario.

**Solution 1**

```cs
public class EntityClassToDestinationEnumConverter : ITypeConverter<EntityClass, DestinationEnum>
{
    public DestinationEnum Convert(EntityClass src, DestinationEnum dest, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (src.IsExempt)
            return DestinationEnum.Exempt;
            
        if (src.IsOverdue)
            return DestinationEnum.Overdue;
            
        switch (src.Status)
        {
            case SourceEnum.InProgress:
                return DestinationEnum.InProgress;
            case SourceEnum.Complete:
                return DestinationEnum.Completed;
            case SourceEnum.AssessmentComplete:
                return DestinationEnum.ConfirmationPending;
            case SourceEnum.Submitted:
                return DestinationEnum.Submitted;
            case SourceEnum.NotSet:
                return DestinationEnum.Unset;
        }
            
        return DestinationEnum.None;
    }
}
```

Your Mapping Profile or `MapperConfiguration` to map from `EntityClass` to `DestinationEnum`.

```cs
MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(config => 
{
    config.CreateMap<EntityClass, DestinationEnum>()
        .ConvertUsing<EntityClassToDestinationEnumConverter>();
});
```

---

**Solution 2**

Or writing a method for the logic **without a custom type resolver class**.

```cs
public static class Helpers
{
    public static DestinationEnum ConvertFromEntityClassToDestinationEnum(EntityClass src)
    {
        if (src.IsExempt)
                return DestinationEnum.Exempt;

        if (src.IsOverdue)
            return DestinationEnum.Overdue;

        switch (src.Status)
        {
            case SourceEnum.InProgress:
                return DestinationEnum.InProgress;
            case SourceEnum.Complete:
                return DestinationEnum.Completed;
            case SourceEnum.AssessmentComplete:
                return DestinationEnum.ConfirmationPending;
            case SourceEnum.Submitted:
                return DestinationEnum.Submitted;
            case SourceEnum.NotSet:
                return DestinationEnum.Unset;
        }

        return DestinationEnum.None;
    }   
}
```

```
MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(config => 
{
    config.CreateMap<EntityClass, DestinationEnum>()
        .ConvertUsing(src => Helpers.ConvertFromEntityClassToDestinationEnum(src));
});
```

[Demo Solution 1 & 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/04sDL8)

Comment: You can use a `Func` with `ConvertUsing`, so I don't see why you need `ConstructUsing`. It might work, but it feels forced. You're not really constructing the destination here, you're taking over the whole mapping, that's a type converter.